# Why does it look like a warning?

Tags: discussion

I went to **Unanswered** page. On the left side you can see something written 398 questions with no up voted answers. Does it effect the site.

[image]

I am asking because I have read that every beta versions site will be beta till 90 days so I think it is like warning to us because it is highlighted. **Is it?**

Comment: This site was in beta from more than two years. But yes, voting is a problem of this site. Some people should learn to vote more often.

Comment: @Mhmd **more than two years**. What does it need to come out from beta version...?

Comment: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1157/take-pride-in-your-community-and-work-to-build-a-site-you-can-be-proud-of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point to having a question and answer site is so people can ask questions and get answers so if there is a lot of questions that aren't answered that's a problem.

If there's a lot of questions that don't have answers or good answers then it is very important that people answer these questions otherwise the site isn't working. 
If you are looking at the "Unanswered questions" tab already then you are probably a user who cares about how many questions don't have answers, so it makes sense for the site to make you realize how important this fact is.

I don't think it affects the site except that a site obviously won't graduate if it's not doing its job which is answering questions.  The number of questions without answers isn't really important as long as other questions do have answers, but if there's a lot of questions without answers and also not a lot of questions with answers then there is a problem.  That's more of a percentage thing than a straight numerical count though like what you see on the Area 51 page (86% answered).

Answer (score 1):

Nah. It's not a warning, afaiu, of a reason why this site isn't graduated yet. StackExchange's flagship site [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) has *[~1.9 million questions with no upvoted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered)*

[image]

The way it's designed, afaiu, is to show the community that their contribution is needed and that there are questions (listed) which don't have a "useful" answers.

Comment: It does effect the site. _http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14922/islam_

Comment: While ours is in beta so it can effect us.